# Table builder rails gem only displaying 5 dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im using the table builder gem in my Rails app and its working fine but only displaying 5 events per month.. Any clue why?

https://github.com/watu/table_builder

```
<div id="calendar">
  <h3 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m") %>
    <%=h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m") %>
  </h3>
  <%= calendar_for @occasions, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
    <%= calendar.head('sun','mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat') %>
    <%= calendar.day(:day_method => :dateg) do |date, occasions| %>
      <%= date.day %>
      <% occasions.each do |occasion| %>
        <%= h(occasion.pname) %><%= '\'s' %>&nbsp;<%= h(occasion.name) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```